# Configuring flake8 plugin when using flakeheaven

Tags: python

I'm trying to configure flake8-quotes plugin to use double, not single, quotes. I'm using flakeheaven in my setup. This behaviour (type of quote) can't be influenced just by enabling / disabling an error code - the official documentation suggests using:

```
[flake8]
inline-quotes = "
```

However, when trying to add this to my pyproject.toml, the new config is not registered. My guess is that flakeheaven overrides those configs - but I don't know how to set up config like that via flakeheaven, as the only thing it enables is enabling / disabling codes. Setting:

```
[tool.flakeheaven]
inline-quotes = "
```

does not help as well.

Comment: flakeheaven has its own incompatible way of configuring flake8 plugins -- what you have is correct for `flake8` -- as such I've removed the `flake8` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony mentioned, flakeheaven config is different from flake8's.

Specifically, as it uses toml, strings must be explicitly specified as such by using quotes for strings ([see the strings section here](https://toml.io/en/)):

```ini
[tool.flakeheaven]
inline-quotes = '"'
```

After changing the configuration file, clear the cache and then run flakeheaven again. Clearing the cache can be forced by setting the env var `FLAKEHEAVEN_CACHE_TIMEOUT=0` (eg: `FLAKEHEAVEN_CACHE_TIMEOUT=0 flakeheaven lint` in linux/osx)